# How to make a scope with a join work in Rails 5?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, scope

I have the following model and associations:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :collaborators, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :collaborators

  scope :open_roles, -> { joins(:collaborators).where(role: { collaborator_id: nil })}
end
```

I want to be able to call Role.open_roles and retrieve all Roles that have no collaborators asigned.

The scope I'm using returns 0 results, and the query I see server side not right:

```
SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" IS NULL
```

What's wrong with the scope I wrote?

Comment: Joins is an represents an "INNER join", the record must be present in both tables. You need to do a "LEFT JOIN".  In Rails 5, you should be able to replace `.joins` with `.left_outer_joins`

Answer (score 0):

Use .left_outer_joins instead of .joins

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the *eager loading* approach for use cases alike. The scope can be defined as

```
scope :open_roles, -> { includes(:collaborators).where(collaborators: { id: nil }) }
```

Using `where` method with `includes` [implies](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` association